# I want to sum using IF condition in SPSS

Tags: spss

I am looking for sum if syntax in SPSS. I have 3 variable. UUID is repeted here. I want to sum the server count for each  UUID (ex:68d92 )and Virt flag P. I want syntax in SPSS. How can I do this?

```
server_conunt    `UUID`           `virt_flag` `P count (excel formula)`                                  ANswer
 1                68d92               P         '=SUMIFS([server_count],[uuid],[@uuid],[virt_flag],"P")  13
 1                68d92               P
 1                68d92              HP
 6                68d92              P
 1                68d92              P
 1                68d92              Hp
 1                68d92               P
 1                68d92               P 

 1                af8b1              P                                                                        7 
 1                af8b1              Hp 
 2                af8b1              P
 1                af8b1              Hp
 1                af8b1              P
```

Comment: I do not get how did you calculated `13` and `7` from the example data. Shouldn't it be `11` and `4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temporary SELECT IF for the condition and AGGREGATE to get the counts in either a new dataset or attached to each case.  For example, to append to existing cases,

```
temporary.
select if virt_flag eq 'P'.
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables
 /break UUID
 /sum_server_conunt = sum(server_conunt).
```

Comment: Sum of `server_conunt` is necessary instead of case count. Made a correction accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much Djhurio and JKP. The syntax is spot-on with my requirement and it helped me a lot to manage huge data at an easy go.